# SageMaker complains that /opt/ml/model does not appear to have a file named config.json

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface

I am using a huggingface model alongside a custom pipeline to deploy my model onto SageMaker, my model.tar.gz structure looks like below:

```
├── added_tokens.json
├── code
│   ├── inference.py
│   ├── pipeline.py
│   └── requirements.txt
├── config.json
├── generation_config.json
├── model-00001-of-00002.safetensors
├── model-00002-of-00002.safetensors
├── model.safetensors.index.json
├── special_tokens_map.json
├── tokenizer_config.json
├── tokenizer.json
└── tokenizer.model
```

I deployed my model via

```py
from sagemaker.huggingface.model import HuggingFaceModel

hub = {
   'HF_TASK':'text-generation'
}
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
   env=hub, 
   model_data="s3://my_model_bucket/model.tar.gz",
   role=role,
   transformers_version="4.28",
   pytorch_version="2.0",
   py_version='py310',
)

# deploy the endpoint endpoint
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.g5.xlarge"
    )
```

However, when I try to invoke the model, here is my response

```json
{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "/opt/ml/model does not appear to have a file named config.json. Checkout \u0027https://huggingface.co//opt/ml/model/None\u0027 for available files."
}
```

Another error is `W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - OSError: /opt/ml/model does not appear to have a file named config.json. Checkout 'https://huggingface.co//opt/ml/model/None' for available files.`

But config.json is clearly in my model directory. Here is my inference.py code

```py
import torch
from typing import Dict
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
from pipeline import MyCustomPipeline

pipeline = None

def model_fn(model_dir):
    print("Loading model from: " + model_dir)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        model_dir,
        local_files_only=True,
    )
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_dir,
        local_files_only=True,
        device_map="auto",
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        trust_remote_code=True,
    )
    pipeline = MyCustomPipeline(model, tokenizer)
    return model, tokenizer

def transform_fn(model, input_data, content_type, accept):
    return pipeline(input_data)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I should have followed all needed steps to deploy a huggingface model onto SageMaker.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error two times.

1. Apparently, the path to S3 that I mentioned was just wrong.
2. When I created the tar.gz file, it was stored in a wrong directory rather than how it was supposed to be.

**Double check the tar file content and see if it is in the format you initially showed.**

```
!tar -xvf "model.tar.gz"
```